# Getting the version number of MySQL build currently in the repo

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu Natty.

What shell command or script would I need to get the version number of the currently active MySQL build in the software repository i.e. after I've done the customary apt-get update and upgrade?!

Right now I know it's 5.1. but I want to be able to query this to know when it changes as I have some shell scripts that rely on this version number.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if it works, but it could eventually be fetched by `$ mysql --version`. But I din't tested it ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ apt-cache show mysql-server
Package: mysql-server
Priority: optional
Section: database
Installed-Size: 96
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian MySQL Maintainers <pkg-mysql-maint@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: all
Source: mysql-5.1
Version: 5.1.58-1ubuntu1
Depends: mysql-server-5.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to know what is installed, or which version of mysqld is currently running?  If the latter:

```
$ mysqladmin version
```

Keep in mind that you may have multiple instances of mysqld running and listening on different ports, so you probably want to know the runtime version of the daemon running on the particular port you are interested in.  (In other words, querying apt-get for info about what is installed is probably not what you want.)

Comment: No, I wanted to know what version of MySQL will be installed when I do `apt-get -y install mysql-server`, but before I actually execute that command.

Comment: your original question does not reflect this thought. Better to copy that into original as a revise. Good luck.